# Black on black textbox when running an html form on tomcat

Tags: eclipse, macos, tomcat

i have an annoying problem, when i'm running from eclipse a jsp page on tomcat 7.0, the text input box of every form is displayed as black on black so that it's impossible to read while you are writing in the box. I tried to install again eclipse but the problem is still unsolved. how can i change change the background color of the textbox? it seems to be a tomcat problem. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat does not set the color of text and background. These parameters can be set in (various ways) in one of these places:

1. In your Java code (in one of your JSP page controllers, on the server). Of course, we are talking of server-side Java code that generates HTML/CSS code for the client.
2. In the web browser used to display the page. The browser can override the fonts, colors and other parameters used by the HTML page.
3. In the web browser that Eclipse uses to display the page.
4. Maybe, even in the Linux Gnome theme that affects Eclipse (or the equivalent desktop theme on Windows and on MacOS).

So, you have to look in these places for a parameter that sets as black the backgound of your input box (the black text is usually the default).